# How to load html in a div from a link inside the div itself

Tags: jquery, cordova

sorry for the title but I don't know ho to explain it.
I'm trying to make my first phonegap app and I have my index.html page generated.
Now inside the page I linked jquerymobile too and I made a simple page with a header, the content and a footer.
Inside the content I have a div and its content is loaded from my server with this code in the page `<head>`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //your code
    $("#test").load("http://www.mywebsite.com/echotest.php");

    });
```

and it works.
Now if the content loaded in the div has a link and I want that the linked page will be loaded in the div itself where the calling link is... What should I do??

I tried changing the code in the head like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#test").load("http://www.myserver.com/echotest.php");

    $('a').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#test").load(this.href);
    });

    });
```

But it doesn't work it just loads a new whole page.
And the same with the last code above also from links outside the div and in the index.html page so static, not generated... but this maybe because of the .live() still have to work on it.

How can I solve this?
Thank you for any help!

**EDIT**

Fixed static links in the index.html with this:

```
$('.mylink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#test').load(link);
});
```

Don't know why I had to add the `class="mylink"` in the `<a>` tags and `$('a').click(function(e){......}` didn't work but as long as it's working...
But still have the problem with dynamic links loaded into the div: they load the external page using all the webview...
I tried also

```
$('.mylink').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#test').load(link);
});
```

but nothing changed :(

**EDIT 2**
It worked only with phonegap desktop and phonegap app to emulate the app... Launched on device it even opens the link in Safari (iOS).
Trying to figure out how to whitelist my domain...

Comment: You can test if live work on it by using console.log("works") for example. And use on instead of live.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into angular.js

https://angularjs.org/

It sounds like you are trying to make a single page application or atleast load some content to a page without navigating away from it. Angular would do just that.

Place the page that you want to link to and update into a view and (which would be just another html file) then have angular load it in a div.